# Calling UpdateAllViews with a CString parameter

Tags: c++, mfc, view

I need to call the [CDocument::UpdateAllViews](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eys41xfw(v=vs.110).aspx) method with following parameters:

- `CView* pSender`
- `LPARAM lHint = 0L`
- **`CString pHint = ""`**

One way, described in MSDN documentation is to pass a [CObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k3448yy(v=vs.110).aspx) derived class and override the `CView::OnUpdate` member function in the CView-derived class.

Is there any other way I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't! Because the last parameter of [UpdateAllViews](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/eys41xfw.aspx) needs a pointer to an object and a `CString` is not derived from `CObject` you need to wrap the string inside a class derived from `CObject`:

```
class CMyHint : public CObject
{
public: 
    CString m_strHint;
};

...
CMyHint hint;
hint.m_strHint = _T("hint");
UpdateAllViews(nullptr,0,&hint);
...

void CMyView::OnUpdate(CView* pSender, LPARAM lHint, CObject* pHint)
{
    CMyHint *pMyHint = static_cast<CMyHint*)(pHint);
    CString str = pMyHint->m_strHint;
...
```

Edit: I just looked into the source code of the MFC. The `CObject *pHint` is nowhere used between `CDocument::UpdateAllViews` and `CView::OnUpdate`. So the pointer is never used as an `CObject`.

So it is possible (**but I would not recommend it**), that you use `reinterpret_cast<CObject*>` to a pointer to a `CString` and later in `CView` you use `reinterpret_cast<CString*>` to get the string pointer again.

Possible but again: **I would not recommend it!**

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was wondering if I could find _any_ string derived from **CObject** :)

Comment: No. CString is plain with no virtual function and a simple destructor!